# next js axios http request to laravel lumen endpoint and display the response data in next js app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, axios, next.js

I have next js app and Axios use to call the lumen endpoints. Axios http client functions are coded in to a seperate folder called services/index.tsx sample code like below.

```
export const register = async (payload: any) => {
  try {
    const endpoint = baseUrl + '/api/register';
    const res = await Axios.post(endpoint, payload)
    return await res.data
  } catch (error) {
   return error.response
  }
}
```

calle to the above register function from the signup.tsx component like below

```
const formik = useFormik({
    onSubmit: (values) => {
        register(values).then(response => {
            console.log(data);
        }).catch(function(error){
            console.log(error)
        })
    }
});
```

Lumen controller json response like below. form validation errors

```
$this->validate($request,[
        'email' => 'required|unique:users,email'
]);

return response()->json(['message' => 'Account Created'],201);
```

how to show the lumen controller response data in the signup.tsx component of the next js app?

Comment: you have syntax error `register(values).then(response` here your getting `response` variable and loggig `data` ? how

Comment: `response.message` should have the data you want. Set it to a state property to display it. FYI, the `await` in `return await res.data` is redundant

Comment: @KamleshPaul I can get the error response in to services/index.tsx  file.  "error.response.data"   but i want to forward that error message into signup.tsx component

Comment: @aseladaskon use `state`

Comment: @KamleshPaul you mean `const [error, setState] = useState()`

Comment: @aseladaskon no `redux` or any gloabl state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @kamlesh

I solved the issue by using redux wrapper with Saga middleware. What I did was create a redux store and dispatch the redux action with saga middleware. These getting started tutorials are helped me a lot. Another point to consider was if you are planning to use server and client side rendering in your next js app, you must use next redux wrapper to handle those request smoothly.

[redux saga doc](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/introduction/GettingStarted) 
[next redux wrapper](https://openbase.com/js/next-redux-wrapper/documentation)